# Counting the number of vowels

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to print no. of vowels. When I run this code I get `1,2,3,4` I intend to print only 4. Where is my mistake and how would I correct it?

```
vowels='a','e','i','o','u'
s= 'hellohello'
count = 0

for letters in s:
   if letters in vowels:
        count+=1
        print (count)
```

Comment: remove indenteaation from print (count)

Answer (score 0):

You're mostly right, but you're printing in the loop rather than at the end.

```
for letters in s:
   if letters in vowels:
        count+=1
# de indent to close the loop
print (count)
```

Answer (score 0):

`count` should be out of `for` loop.So that it prints only once.

```
vowels='a','e','i','o','u'
s= 'hellohello'
count = 0 
for letters in s:
     if letters in vowels: 
           count+=1 
print (count)
```